# How to keep header background image at a constant horizontal point in viewport

Tags: html, css

In my header section, I want to have a background image that fills the right side of the viewport but stays at a constant distance relative to the text content in the header regardless of viewport width.

The HTML and CSS code is along the lines of:

```html
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div id="header-content"> 
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
                <etc.> ... </etc.>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That places the header image at my monitor resolution exactly 100px away from the header content but obviously, as the screen resolution changes, the image position changes relative to the header text content and starts to overlap.

This screenshot is how things look at my screen resolution. I want to keep that header image at that same distance from the header content regardless of viewport width and it's okay if the header image goes off the right of the screen as the screen size changes as long as it stays at the same distance relative to the text to the left of it. I've tried various different background position types like calc and pixel positioning but I can't really get what I'm looking for at the larger resolutions. For smaller devices, I've gone with a different centered layout for this header but for the larger resolutions I would like to keep this layout constant. [image]

Comment: There is no minimal code to reproduce your problem. And what happens with image when screen resolution gets on mobile? It can't be away for 100px the whole time..

Comment: @asobak as I've already explained clearly in the post: "For smaller devices, I've gone with a different centered layout for this header but for the larger resolutions I would like to keep this layout constant."

Comment: Yeah, and where is the margin between mobile and larger screens?

Comment: At around max-width 820px, I adapt down to a text-align centered layout for the header with a lighter image behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `background` use `<img>` tag with some `css` like this:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#header-wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
.image{
  width:45%;
  margin-left:auto;
  
}
.image img{
width:100%;
}
#header-content {
    width:auto;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="header-content"> 
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
            <etc.> ... </etc.>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That does seem to move the image around relative to the text though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I figured something that will work in this case using absolute positioning:

```
#header-image {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:45%;
    margin-left:55%;
    background:url(../images/header.png) no-repeat;
}
```